# Phonegap push notification using pushwoosh and pushsharp

Tags: c#, push-notification, phonegap-build, pushsharp, pushwoosh

I am using pushwoosh plugin in my phonegap mobile app for IOS and Android push notification. using the pushwoosh I get the device token, after that I am saving the device token in my server, finally I am pushing the message from my server using the pushsharp library.I am getting the notifications in IOS but in Android I didn't get any notification. but the notification is successfully sent from the pushsharp library. I didn't get any exception, I see "NotificationSent" method is triggering. below is the json string I am sending using pushsharp. is there any specific format I need to send for android? but if I send the message from pushwoosh account it's working.

```
"{"message":"Hello","title":"Message From App"}"
```

Comment: why is it tagged with c#

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Pushwoosh API for this?

Comment: I was expecting an answer sir, not another question.